# Add external library to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, windows, methods, phpmyadmin

I downloaded the library from https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys and I need to add it to phpmyadmin to use it with a mysql database but I can't find the way, I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a library for phpMyAdmin but for MySQL. Moreover, the included script and makefile are intended for a Unix-like server environment, not your Windows.